# Segmented Hash Maps. Do more segments increase or decrease performance?

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap

I'm trying to understand how segmented hash maps work. I understand that they make hashmaps more thread safe, but I'm not clear as to whether or not divided data into segments will increase the overall number of operations that can be performed on a given hash map per second.

For example, if I had a hash map with 10,000 elements and gradually increased the number of segments, would I see an increase or decrease in the program's throughput and operations per second?

Comment: Are you asking about the `concurrencyLevel` parameter of `ConcurrentHashMap`? Or do you mean something else with "segmented map"?

Comment: Hi Meriton, I'm talking about concurrent Hash maps yes. I've read about segmentation in concurrent hash maps and I'm unsure about how they affect performance. As each segment is essentially a lock, surely more segments slow down the program as that means some methods and operations have to wait?

Answer (score 0):

The concurrencyLevel parameter has no effect in modern implementations and only exists to preserve API compatibility with earlier versions of the JDK, or as the Javadoc puts it:

> Also, for compatibility with previous versions of this class, constructors may optionally specify an expected `concurrencyLevel` as an additional hint for internal sizing.

It is [implemented](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/dc2f0c40399a/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#l892) as follows:

```
public ConcurrentHashMap(int initialCapacity,
                         float loadFactor, int concurrencyLevel) {
    if (!(loadFactor > 0.0f) || initialCapacity < 0 || concurrencyLevel <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    if (initialCapacity < concurrencyLevel)   // Use at least as many bins
        initialCapacity = concurrencyLevel;   // as estimated threads
    long size = (long)(1.0 + (long)initialCapacity / loadFactor);
    int cap = (size >= (long)MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) ?
        MAXIMUM_CAPACITY : tableSizeFor((int)size);
    this.sizeCtl = cap;
}
```

That is, `concurrencyLevel` merely overrides the `initialCapacity` if the user has specified an unrealistically low `initialCapacity`. That's all.

Moreover, this merely sets the initial capacity of the map; the actual capacity will grow with the number of entries (as directed by `loadFactor`).

In summary, `concurrencyLevel` has no lasting effect in all but the most obscure of usecases (a map with ill-specified initial capacity that contains less entries than threads accessing it and is heavily contested because all threads spend most of their time interacting with that map).

You also asked:

> As each segment is essentially a lock, surely more segments slow down the program as that means some methods and operations have to wait?

To get or put a value, a thread will only lock the segment that contains it. That is, partitioning the map into more segments will not cause more locks to be acquired or released in every operation, but reduce the probability of lock contention because there are less entries per segment.

Also, it is worth noting that many methods in ConcurrentHashMap are wait-free. For instance, here is the method that gets a value:

```
public V get(Object key) {
    Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> e, p; int n, eh; K ek;
    int h = spread(key.hashCode());
    if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&
        (e = tabAt(tab, (n - 1) & h)) != null) {
        if ((eh = e.hash) == h) {
            if ((ek = e.key) == key || (ek != null && key.equals(ek)))
                return e.val;
        }
        else if (eh < 0)
            return (p = e.find(h, key)) != null ? p.val : null;
        while ((e = e.next) != null) {
            if (e.hash == h &&
                ((ek = e.key) == key || (ek != null && key.equals(ek))))
                return e.val;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```